# Scala Spark : trying to avoid type erasure when using overload

Tags: scala, apache-spark, overloading, type-erasure, dstream

I'm relatively new to Scala/Spark

I'm trying to overload one function depending on the class type into a DStream

```
def persist(service1DStream: DStream[Service1]): Unit = {...}
def persist(service2DStream: DStream[Service2]): Unit = {...}
```

I'm getting a compilation error:

`persist(_root_.org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream) is already defined in the scope`

Seems that it's due to type erasure.
How to make compiler recognize that `DStream[Service1]` is different from `DStream[Service2]`

Thank you

Comment: You can use scala pattern matching:
    def persist(serviceDStream: DStream[_]) = { 
    serviceDStream match {
    case  DStream[Service1] => doStuffForService1
    }}

Answer (score 0):

```
def persist(serviceDStream: DStream[Any]): Unit = serviceDStream match {
case _: DStream[Service1] => println("it is a Service1")
case _: DStream[Service2] => println("it is a Service2")    
case _ => println("who knows")     
}
```

improved solution re `runtime type erasure` using `shapeless` more info [shapeless-guide](http://underscore.io/books/shapeless-guide/):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream
import shapeless.TypeCase

object Test {

 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .getOrCreate()

case class Service1 (a: String)
case class Service2 (a: Int)

val Service1Typed = TypeCase[DStream[Service1]]
val Service2Typed    = TypeCase[DStream[Service2]]

def persist(serviceDStream: DStream[Any]): Unit = serviceDStream match {

  case Service1Typed => println("it is a Service1")
  case Service2Typed => println("it is a Service2")
  case _ => println("who knows")
}
```

}

}

You can also use `import scala.reflect.ClassTag`  more info: [ClassTag example](https://medium.com/byte-code/overcoming-type-erasure-in-scala-8f2422070d20)

Comment: Same issue @karol 

`on-variable type argument Service1 in type pattern org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[Service1] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
[warn]     case _ :DStream[Service1] => persistService1 _`

In Scala generics are erased at runtime, thus type of DStream[Service1] and DStream[Service2] are actually the same

Comment: @Fares, indeed you are correct, have a look at shapeless or ClassTag to overcome it. I updated my answer.